# Error starting Docker Quickstart

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am using Docker Toolbox on Win 7.

Here is the error I get:
Error checking TLS connection: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err : exit status 255
output :

Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err : exit status 255
output :
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP

Comment: What version of boot2docker/docker are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you get that error?
I found this issue https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/317 it describes something like your error.

They resolved recreating the default machine. Are you able to try this stuff?